# can a lookup an akka actor address from configuration?

Tags: akka

When using Akka 2.0, Is there a way to get an ActorRef to a remote actor but have the address of the actor I am looking up come from configuration instead of specifying it programatically?  I want to, for instance use

```
AkkaSystem("mysystem").actorFor("akka://system@remotehost/user/whatever")
```

but I want to be able to change remotehost just by changing my
application.conf.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can retrieve arbitrary information from the `Config` object contained in the `ActorSystem` (or you could parse external sources with `ConfigFactory` yourself):

```scala
val system = AkkaSystem("mysystem")
val config = system.settings.config
val remotePath = config.getString("my-config.serviceA")
val ref = system.actorFor(remotePath)
```

together with defining some string in the configuration at the path given above. You can then also use the power of the Config library to piece together the path (e.g. factor out the remote node’s address etc.):

```rb
my-config {
  remotenode = "akka://sys@remote.node:2134"
  serviceA = ${my-config.remotenode}/service/A
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define deployment path in the configuration.
From [Akka docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.0/java/remoting.html):

```
akka {
  actor {
    deployment {
      /sampleActor {
        remote = "akka.tcp://sampleActorSystem@127.0.0.1:2553"
      }
    }
  }
}

ActorRef actor = system.actorOf(Props.create(SampleActor.class), "sampleActor");
```